# Prepress-quality printing from Google Earth

Tags: pdf, google-earth

*disclaimer: Google Earth newbie question*

I have a last-minute request from a client who needs to print out PDFs (for pre-press) with custom maps (ranging from continental down to sub-national size) and pins and city names for specific cities.

I can easily produce a klm file with the cities and coordinates, which displays fine in Google Earth.

Is there a built-in zoom-in and print function in Google Earth that would output a basic political map, represent cities as dots (being able to size them up or down to reflect custom population densities would be a plus) and label them with a custom city name?

Alternatively, is there an app or add-on that would let me do that?

Comment: You are aware of the fact that Google Earth does not have political maps available?

Comment: Thanks @Neo. Actually you can overlay your own. But that doesn't solve my pre-press printing problem, far from it.

Answer (score 1):

Printing maps using material from Google Earth is a violation of copyright and [Googles guidelines for the maps](http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html). You should buy a license to use a commercially available map or find maps without copyright restrictions. Perhaps [openstreetmaps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) might suit your needs - be aware that they have their own open source-style licensing model which may not be suitable for your needs.

Comment: The Pro edition allows printing. I suppose it must then be covered by the license –

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out Google Earth is not what I need.

I'm now testing indiemapper.com which looks promising. It's got pre-built political maps in a variety of projections, and you can overlay a custom kml file.